# Alignment of 3 elements (Left, Right 1, Right 2)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, alignment

I want to design a layout view for my project. The layout view has an image on the left corner and at the right corner (same line) there will be 2 lines of words, one at line 1 and another at line 2. 
How do I achieve that?

```
<body>
<div>
<img src = "image" alt ="Logo" height = "120" width = "170"/>
<div class = "r">Item 1.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So far I can do left and 1 item on the right.

```
<body>
<div>
<img src = "Image" alt ="Logo" height = "120" width = "170"/>
<div class = "r">Item 1.</div>
**<div class = "r">Item 2.</div>**
</div>
</body>
```

If I added in the second item it will appear at the line after the image. What I want is both lines on the right will be in the same alignment with the image on the left.

My css file is something like

```
        .r 
        {
            float:right;
            width: 33%;
        }
        .l
        {
            float:left;
            width: 33%;
        }    
        .c 
        {
            text-align:center;
            width: 34%;
        }
```

Comment: why dont you try float left for .c too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/cQEFY/)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="image">
    <img src = "image" alt ="Logo" height = "120" width = "170"/>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
    <p>1st line</p>
    <p>2nd line</p>
 </div>
</div>


 .container
 {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:blue;
 }
 .image
 {
  float:left;   
  height:120px;
  width:170px;
  background-color:red;
 }
 .right
 {
  float:left;
  width:300px;   
  height:120px;
  background-color:green;
 }
```